# Is there a way to download multiple zip at once using PHP

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I am downloading multiple files in zip using PHP and its working perfectly fine. I am collecting all files required and downloading them as parent.zip file.

Now since there are large number of files in my zip, i want to split the zip download into parts. say when a user clicks the button i want to download child1.zip, child2.zip and childn.zip depending upon the parts generated by the logic. How could i do this in PHP.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot send more than one attachment per response.

Your best bet would be to make the request accept a parameter of `part number`, write the logic to generate only that zip part and send that particular file as an attachment to that particular response.

Then on the client side you can simultaneously issue several 'parallel' requests to the download, each with the part number.

More to the point, you will have to write first one handler which generates all the parts on the server side and returns the number of files generated in response.  That response is then used to fire several concurrent requests to the second handler with the part number parameter, each will get its respective part as response.

Comment: Hi thanks for you reply, what are the ways in which i can fire several parallel concurrent  requests using PHP or do i have to use javascript / AJAX?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion would be to send ajax request and get the list of zip files to be downloaded which is created temporarily in server and use client side javascript to process the download, or the other option would be to send multiple request per file download.

Comment: Hi Could you please share with me some sample JavaScript code which can process the download. Thanks

Comment: Try this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993468/php-header-to-download-multiple-files-in-loop